# Set output directories in turbo c++

Tags: directory, output, turbo-c++

By mistake, I have changed the output directory in turbo c++. I have tried to set but i don't remember exact path. Can anyone help me to set the path of that directory ?

Answer (score 0):

go to **Options -> Directories**

You'll get 4 text fields.

- Include Libraries
- Library Libraries
- Output Libraries
- Source Libraries

See if any path is present in the "Include library" field by default. If there is any content, copy the same to the other three fields as well.

If there isn't any content in any of the fields, type the root directory, usually "C:" or "D:" or the directory in which you've installed Turbo C, followed by the installation folder. Usually, its "tc".

After copying the content to the other text fields, press OK.